# Div won't stretch to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a `<div>` stretch to the bottom of the page.
I want this `<div>` to be something like a bar all along the left side of my page. It does stretch along the left side when I open the page but when I'm scrolling down it won't stretch anymore.
The thing is I have multiple `<div>`s wrapped inside one another, but this one I am talking about is child only of `<html>` and `<body>` elements.
I tried a lot of things to make it work properly but `height:auto;`, `height:100%;` or `height:inherit;` don't seem to work, but it works if I use `height:000px;`.
I should also mention that both `<html>` and `<body>` have `height:100%;` and `width:100%;`.

The code looks like this:

```
  .leftbar {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    margin-top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

What confuses me even more is that I also have a footer on the bottom side of my page but it works great. It stretches as much as I need it to.
The code for it looks like this:

```
.footer {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Could you tell me pls why that left side bar won't stretch?

Comment: I think I knew your problem, but I cannot ascertain my assumption. Can you please post a complete snippet summarizing the problem?

Comment: That is literally everything there is about this `<div>`. `<body>
<div class="leftbar">
</div>`   here's the html and here are the `<html>` and `<body>` in css:: `html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}`
         
`body {
background-image:url("hp1_background.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 100% 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}`

Answer (score 2):

You could try

`height: 100vh;`

Remember `height: 100%` is filling 100% height of its parent container. If the parent container isn't reaching the bottom, then the leftbar can't.

Comment: `min-height: 100vh;` and `height: 100vh;` didn't solve the problem. Since my `<div>` is child only of `<html>` and `<body>` I don't see how they wouldn't reach the bottom. Shouldn't they cover everything?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS Grid instead of floating divs to create this layout. Here's a sample:

```css
/* Container */
.container {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Grid container */
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
      [row1-start] "sidebar content" 90vh [row1-end]
      [row2-start] "footer footer" auto [row2-end]
      / 15vw auto; /* The width of each column */
}


/* Sidebar */
.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}


/* Content */
.content {
  grid-area: content;
}


/* Footer */
.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<body class='container'>
  <div class='grid'>
      <div class='sidebar'>This is the sidebar</div>
      <div class='content'>This is the main content</div>
      <footer class='footer'>This is the footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Grids systems have many advantages over using floats some include:

- Easier to read
- Can be made responsive using media queries easily
- The grid can be expanded later on easily
- You don't get confused why your layout randomly breaks with floats

An alternative method to Grid would be Flexbox.

Docs:

- [A great tutorial on CSS Grids by CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)
- [A great tutorial on CSS Flexbox by CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I have no idea what Grids and Flexbox are but I'll be sure to look into them.

Answer (score 1):

The key point to cover your need  is using: `height: 100vh`

However, you have to aware that if the content of `sidebar` is longer than `sidebar` container, `sidebar` background will be missing when you scroll down over `100vh`.

So, using `min-height: 100vh` is better.

Hope this helps.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container::after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
}

.main-container {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 1200px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background: #ddd;
}

.footer {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-container">
    This main container is very long.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  Yay! you found footer.
</div>
```